# How do I get the next item in an array when I am given the first element via pinvoke?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using an api that has method defined as follows:

```
[DllImport("icsneo40.dll")]
public static extern Int32 icsneoGetMessages(Int32 hObject, ref icsSpyMessage pMsg, ref          Int32 pNumberOfMessages, ref Int32 pNumberOfErrors);
```

with `icsSpyMessage` parameter described as:

> pMsg [out]
>   This is the address of the first element of an array of
>   icsSpyMessage structures.         This array will be loaded with
>   messages received by the hardware. This array must be sized to fit
>   20,000 icsSpyMessage structures

My question is how do I access the other elements in the array when all I have is the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing an array you should declare the `icsSpyMessage` to be an array:

```
[DllImport("icsneo40.dll")]
public static extern Int32 icsneoGetMessages(
    Int32 hObject, 
    [Out] icsSpyMessage[] pMsg,
    ref Int32 pNumberOfMessages, 
    ref Int32 pNumberOfErrors
);
```

The [out] attribute instructs the p/invoke marshaller to marshal the native memory back to your managed array of structs. The marshaller will marshal elements according to the length of the managed array.

So you need to allocate this array before you call the function. The API you are calling requires that you provide an array of at least 20,000 elements.

```
icsSpyMessage[] pMsg = new icsSpyMessage[20000];
Int32 result = icsneoGetMessages(hObject, pMsg, 
    ref pNumberOfMessages, ref pNumberOfErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
[DllImport("icsneo40.dll")]

public static extern Int32 icsneoGetMessages(
    Int32 hObject, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)]
    out icsSpyMessage[] pMsg, 
    ref Int32 pNumberOfMessages, 
    ref Int32 pNumberOfErrors
);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It should no use an `out` parameter. That should be removed. Instead you need the `[out]` attribute. See my answer. And as it happens there's no need for the `MarshalAs` since the default behaviour is to marshal the entire array. I guess the SizeParamIndex  could be valuable for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things? All that is a pointer that points to a struct of some sort or an array of structs. Therefore declare your array of 20k size

icsSpyMessage myMessages[20000];

pass it to this method as follows:

int result = icsneoGetMessages(
blahh, 
myMessages[0], // <<== this is a pointer to first element of struct or object... 
blahh, 
blahh);

When you get the messages, you can iterate through via "foreach(icsSpyMessage item in myMessages) { ... }

hope this helps..